# Register route using app container Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, appcontainer

I would like to register my routes (endpoints) dynamically in **Laravel**. I am not using **routes.php**, yet I want to register routes using

```
$this->app->get()
```

or similiar, in service provider. Furthermore I would like also to add a middleware this way to dynamically registered route.

Comment: You mean register them and persist them? So using database?

Comment: Routes are written in json file. Service provider registers them using app container.. Since I am not using routes.php file but json file instead, I want to know how to add middleware to specific routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at your `RouteServiceProvider@map` in `App\Providers` to see how Laravel imports the `routes.php` file.

You can then import your JSON file convert it to an array and loop through it.

Your JSON file can look like this

```
[
    {
        "method": "get",
        "uri": "/profile",
        "action": {
            "as": "profile",
            "uses": "UserController@showProfile",
            "middleware": "auth"
        }
    }
]
```

When you decode this you can then do something like that

```
\Route::$method($uri, $action);
```

Comment: It helped me.. Answer is:                                                                           $this->app->$httpVerb($value->endpoint,["uses" => $value->controller, "middleware"=> "relation"]);